# Java,Spring,Remember me Option for Login.jsp page?

Tags: java, spring, session-cookies

Actually i'm developing Spring Annotation based Application. In that Login.jsp file is their.

When User enter Details and click remember me check box that cookie remember in browser same gmail service (stay in).

So in that i'm search in google,i'm finding Spring also provide Remember me Functionality, But it take supported Jar file.

Is their any Simple way for Storing Cookies on browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `@SessionAttribute` or `@CookieValue` annotation of spring-mvc. Read more about it on the [spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

Comment: Please provide sample code for this..Using @CookieValue Annotation

Comment: There are plenty examples on the Spring manual link above, or search for yourself